# Import powerbi-client-vue-js.umd.js with importmap leads to Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'defineComponent')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, powerbi-embedded, import-maps

below follows the code sample that should work out-of-the-box by Microsoft documentation: https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-client-vue-js

I would like to integrate the module powerbi-client-vue-js with the importmap approach, but something goes wrong at import-time for `PowerBIReportEmbed` component that makes me harder to debug the error above:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'defineComponent')`
[image]

I have created a public example dashboard. The access token should not be needed but it was one of thousands of examples I have followed and I leave it there.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Play PowerBI Client VueJS</title>
    <script type="importmap">
    { "imports": 
        { "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js", 
          "vuetify": "https://unpkg.com/vuetify@3.5.3/dist/vuetify.esm.js",
          "powerbi-report-authoring": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/powerbi-report-authoring@2.0.0/+esm",
          "powerbi-router": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/powerbi-router@0.1.5/+esm",
          "powerbi-models": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/powerbi-models@1.14.0/+esm",
          "powerbi-client": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/powerbi-client@2.22.4/+esm",
          "powerbi-client-vue-js": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/powerbi-client-vue-js@1.0.3/+esm",
          "window-post-message-proxy": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ont-community/window-post-message-proxy@0.2.14/+esm",
          "http-post-message": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/http-post-message@0.2.3/+esm"
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="app" class="mt-8 mb-4">
        <PowerBIReportEmbed
            :embed-config="reportConfig"
            css-class-name="reportClass"
            :phased-embedding={false}
            :event-handlers="reportHandlers"
        >
        </PowerBIReportEmbed> 
    </div>

<script type="module" lang="js">
  import { createApp, ref } from 'vue'
  import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

  import pbi from 'powerbi-client';
  import "powerbi-report-authoring"
  import { PowerBIReportEmbed } from 'powerbi-client-vue-js'

  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    theme: {
        defaultTheme: 'light'
    }
  })

  createApp({
      data: () => ({
        report: undefined,
        reportConfig: {
            type: "report",
            id: "74d7db75-6278-4066-8d7d-b67693080566",
            embedUrl: "https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiYWI5OGViZjItYmZmNi00NmYwLTlmMjAtYjc5ODBiM2Q4NDhhIiwidCI6IjA1NGMzYmE3LTlhNDMtNGM4Ny05YmRiLThiNGYyZTJlYmRkYyIsImMiOjl9",
            accessToken: "H4sIAAAAAAAEAC2WxQ7siBVE_-VtHclMkWZht6nNTDszMzvKv6ejmf1dHd06Vf_5YyZPPyX5n3__YZDMcrJrhKxmCmmvHoHqi6KOje0HYbLpYhbDVGIchTJFGhkloNfCiUssmA3Qg54n5IcLtO7yRPCnCB4JMaw4P0vV-DSqGiXkRjb0EySIkSpppdAjmVv4PJkmlSoupnsfDKHG_bzRBPTvlanEgOGZQ5OOOM3FoVAxcEftadNaQgeh1VNOdR_pXqGzL025aet-V-mimY05V07E72zJ2hpvsEJBPEnKKAAi37pLPGKW-qZGHkNCbTSTzDGVMLlI6J6pweqR-Hl2u-e1qNeVvxJXOEiK3AFIyF9IRnp3fna1b2yyLQHOM-ueegjkHW3xAz_BTlqPrNd7tb5PIDNQOZXDNDdbB2VBAu1-KNxK0bg9Lpj2nl3awFGfLJwiEb0XvJ79u1srTyLYYwLfMs56voZrp284uH3isI3ikm1dyXhH-qXRRz4sNnIFLM4oWD_ZaDQN880bY6cS4quz5kbflit5hQviGyelSeNIydiql-pQ7J0SDiF_UK6Id8kXN29vsjcglXT74PilMOg03UwPyTOUEScd0KopEsgq0jIgn_Srb6-yVZ_nfiFE4FS4Ed-iGS-WWSZUE6hcdWxGOwXlIEVYvYmenuC9VDUqWXC4iHpj3aNG5Itoa5gXAjt8-zAJ74MRYH1KfU6TofBb6toeExYk65y6h8x7xJmVD9QLszm1dmExxSPyMlU6OwmWOCGmXGbxvoGdrPXJJIrj0dI1iwYzYDTlycV8errhaKXH3DpnaP06I_3-aDbg9Hk-w3RGDrBrXTIO7PR0x_T7VBF8-d8LEiKKeip4tuiLAZiHaGVOxsUKsCU7AnlgSkXUGWebSKelw1gTIW_YmO3z6w8bJJVwwyywlhQVBxjJy1X4-c57uVJQUgInL99nBRPdwi5Xg64Ykl5NC31Dg-VttbThT37NLuf4geDYRupYasXG9OguxC8wZvtZH2l3vOydGnmQoIB4azkIA-uDAYe6O7SZIZLv1yPMhbJKbzTKMApLD55xswFtD3lzvNbu24PJaVJP-L4X6rsb5iProLUDK33KVs85BjQtWaJTZ3kbsBhj8IEkCJQm84qR3G2BOnOKWZYgmLEhguodHYUrMdQaq8PHGvdRUxduod_Ml90P18YUw3zzIbtgxqMV8PeemIO80YAPRfOdS3JDtjMbKzBVydCfE8O45sQBOtzxRbTrAIO_NukoIps6u9vrlVZbqtICKzEr_AjGeHBVhpCvjfHQ4Hnwj3UmPxnU364fgl89GmAHUJdSyodCGoWZfhg4TF0Fq48W0u3p4j0G2V3cFFM00lb-wt2kyONxoIMQMmbeyDIArNXD1p70PqrITuSxwOiyuL4Pm4PCeH0RqfsU7k1qX3B97b6AJ1uy-GrDalOkyd_HH0QW-wZ5VmhQIUE0I4S6wzSpCPDmFIqCS5_5sBAMJW03qw1upFRi64q8WWXsRKglm4TWZUmf2L5uKJuMRgGHhTqiQqJS2f_SN4wTGS1Om3n2XGNR4z6CpncF8HMnDpWsge2JmspiG6Ujatm-zAG_n5vc0YzorxJGwsCBoloysbJXZQ8-nAM0xFSISVYIiyuSd9vBVWUtojwDi_nRUHJJOtLuhdxplMWoM094AVzc6N0hYCJJwWROT780DxLtKSrMQZfAS2ryqV9O5BiOdP8ICt83T_kX8ml1refK0LCQpyAjpBltqs_R2VFF6lGQ-zjRWVoPzp4NQx-NHVe6UPnPB3r65hP0bTxxXeVw5MtjUX0VV5QzoYRuMtukD6U0bsaSSHDqKncT_mk7mUDagvL2gfDNGhbmi28i31WueR9Tbu5aJTChNcWsfx8_hyTbQppaLMt4hLpCN7ioMzU-FiFHLj0wZbKxCQg1XICCyRkFKWpwk7OO9PRzNfGAP744RBwSQAK2z6MxDEvAcKac-vm1HijAfEWD_Q76qF66N4rj0RFkx9NUPfuZsF7BRk_xjVTm0G3AtXq4VlwEEGah9ziUXU7ZIJKkHjsGr7f5MJItEhbZnvWJ05nKFraj81f4IPy9Z9JGZ5XWR1_fh2SgPAax1vy2jyo21XgkKd3RkI0Hpd6AwZ668pIGLyIHDX86qWVj7pZerzyEAoLXGB_hPCjyBKknIFFIk7090UmeWhUT_6JI-WTIm5w3skyR0IjPdPQIz4RRcga7bSRJqCOmVYmxZS4VDRfel-II8ATVLp1kBmMd0tr63H3Xw1DeRN-Kzk7SB6aBMaytIQWSHoFB0BEmt2zt2xyt9iLndBLTCGA6MLqtBdWpnlnZvEpWf8mBa2Ce-sGZbU10ZVLFRzYsbIDaUsIQuy_lE0i7O2g5k873dXrH6_x5cmTIClNXqD4EmiX0eEKR-BStSDDuBF22OksR3HugtqeWgcfkBGBvD-d_qyfkJJMSPtdZLd2HKJXN184V8PCQj3j4HECPIMnKU_MgfoMbWMLd-PaPfnnhHX6UEbNMR0RoHQnjKur0wutA66-__vzrz0_48z4pxfObaUmEcCu7rSZ3fE6PQqbxegUN16Cm_AEVRnyVhWkwZMqeiSb6FZQBFaTeLXuSkr0JkTnjXy7atos96C-0JCaEgsHmk1vkWDj57vGgZ1j8NpXJKhYxtQJA0dKbXz--b7CaS-7cSIasYRjTWjf0Yy52QUgs86kf8Tvmu81Qwugb0VY4pxeGqR0LPBJ8hTCWtfcVIftrgoN7dID1aw21DM2tD7KqjYejoZXZzWtOfL8h4RW766l3169Dn21bMyK_WSFGyrVhbqsBz5f0X-3I-WvpHxCIMJaQ7ubAUI80OeY3Ozhy5kahY7G3cQTOsChHgGJQBxygcPdLwIJ0vAeZzxGMFeHmH8zPXBfr1_9RdunmjJ8tHeYl6OJ4rcQeNf--cppqTPZjLX5nJuRX3RQGmdjyq5UPTaV--uS0rq83cZzROikrQ-ZyGN1sqvdPcAGmTnmRG6k2DrPhS7ZpyQpPgTqIKeRFUxqS7sWu6gU4KPLdeiX8eK0ooKfPD71kHNAck5nqPhvkKKuJmB15TBqTsHPq7vhHu-YGsp4cf50ag5PFn9rTrUPOD-I84YCUv4cDbo4F1D7G6K_1-8Nu-_AHXFeLaKMD27Xb0gm6vMbDZ85vW33Cbqx9ByJOI4DZFas4OXhC2J4q4TSNrQfk5Ym8FMUGlOZL6A4xT9k72I57zFvF140V-_tbq1x_vcfPipr05cEusNkNqG4D9jVSPcszkZfiV77Vgtz4LQH_x_zf_wGPhDTtmgwAAA==.eyJjbHVzdGVyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9XQUJJLVVTLU5PUlRILUNFTlRSQUwtcmVkaXJlY3QuYW5hbHlzaXMud2luZG93cy5uZXQiLCJleHAiOjE3MDg0NDgwMjksImFsbG93QWNjZXNzT3ZlclB1YmxpY0ludGVybmV0Ijp0cnVlfQ==",
            tokenType: null,
        },
    }),
    methods: {
        reportHandlers() { 
            console.log("8")
            new Map([
                ['loaded', () => console.log('Report loaded')],
                ['rendered', () => console.log('Report rendered')],
                ['error', (event) => console.log(event.detail)]
            ])
        }
    }
  }).use(vuetify).use(PowerBIReportEmbed).mount('#app')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried also the plain `powerbi-client` approach following the SO question: [Power BI embed + VueJS error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'powerBiEmbed' of null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379381/power-bi-embed-vuejs-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-powerbiembed-of)

and I succeed in embedding the report, but not to handle events with `this.report.on("rendered")` in example.

I would really like to use the module provided by MS to embed PowerBI with VueJS 3. Moreover I use vuetify but I think it doen't matter.

Can you please tell me why an object is null/undefined so that the `.defineComponent` attribute raises this error? And how to debug such import errors? console.log/debugger doesn't help too much.

Thank you in advance
fero aka feroda